# The Irreducible Corepresentations of the eight-dimensional Kac-Paljutkin Quantum Group

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

I asked this question on [Math.Stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430687/the-irreducible-corepresentations-of-the-eight-dimensional-kac-paljutkin-quantum) but have not had any answers.

**Question**

What are the irreducible corepresentations of the eight-dimensional Kac-Paljutkin Quantum Group, $A$?

The trivial corepresentation is given by $\Delta_{|\mathbb{C}1_A}$ where $1_A$ is just the unit.

By my reckoning there should be seven more one dimensional invariant subspaces and hence irreducible corepresentations.

**The eight-dimensional Kac-Paljutkin Quantum Group**

Here we give the defining relations and the main structure of an eight-dimensional quantum group introduced by Kac and Paljutkin. This is actually the smallest finite quantum groups that is not a group algebra. In other words, it is the non-commutative C*-Hopf algebra of smallest dimension.

Consider the multi-matrix algebra $$A=\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}\oplus M_2(\mathbb{C}),$$
with the usual multiplication and involution. We shall use the basis $e_1=(1,0,0,0,0)$ (with $e_2,\,e_3,\,e_4$ defined in the same way) and

$$ a_{11}=0+ 0+ 0+ 0+\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right),$$

with the other $a_{ij}$ defined in the same way. The algebra $A$ is an eight-dimensional C*-algebra. Its unit is of course  $1_A=e_1+e_2+e_3+e_4+a_{11}+a_{22}$. The following defines a comultiplication on $A$,

$ \scriptsize{  \Delta(e_1)=e_1\otimes e_1+e_2\otimes e_2+e_3\otimes e_3+e_4\otimes e_4+\frac{1}{2}a_{11}\otimes a_{11}+\frac{1}{2}a_{12}\otimes a_{12}+\frac{1}{2}a_{21}\otimes a_{21}+\frac{1}{2}a_{22}\otimes a_{22}}$
$ \scriptsize{ \Delta(e_2)=e_1\otimes e_2+e_2\otimes e_1+e_3\otimes e_4+e_4\otimes e_3+ \frac{1}{2}a_{11}\otimes a_{22}+\frac{1}{2}a_{22}\otimes a_{11}+\frac{i}{2}a_{21}\otimes a_{12}-\frac{i}{2}a_{12}\otimes a_{21}}$
$ \scriptsize{  \Delta(e_3)=e_1\otimes e_3+e_3\otimes e_1+e_2\otimes e_4+e_4\otimes e_2+ \frac{1}{2}a_{11}\otimes a_{22}+\frac{1}{2}a_{22}\otimes a_{11}-\frac{i}{2}a_{21}\otimes a_{12}+\frac{i}{2}a_{12}\otimes a_{21}}$
$ \scriptsize{  \Delta(e_4)=e_1\otimes e_4+e_4\otimes e_1+e_2\otimes e_3+e_3\otimes e_2+ \frac{1}{2}a_{11}\otimes a_{11}+\frac{1}{2}a_{22}\otimes a_{22}-\frac{1}{2}a_{12}\otimes a_{12}-\frac{1}{2}a_{21}\otimes a_{21}}$
$ \scriptsize{  \Delta(a_{11})=e_1\otimes a_{11}+a_{11}\otimes e_1+e_2\otimes a_{22}+a_{22}\otimes e_2+e_3\otimes a_{22}+a_{22}\otimes e_3+e_4\otimes a_{11}+a_{11}\otimes e_4}$
$ \scriptsize{  \Delta(a_{12})=e_1\otimes a_{12}+a_{12}\otimes e_1+ie_2\otimes a_{21}-ia_{12}\otimes e_2-ie_3\otimes a_{21}+ia_{21}\otimes e_3-e_4\otimes a_{12}-a_{12}\otimes e_4}$
$ \scriptsize{  \Delta(a_{21})=e_1\otimes a_{21}+a_{21}\otimes e_1-ie_2\otimes a_{12}+ia_{12}\otimes e_2+ ie_3\otimes a_{12}-ia_{12}\otimes e_3-e_4\otimes a_{21}-a_{21}\otimes e_4}$
$ \scriptsize{  \Delta(a_{22})=e_1\otimes a_{22}+a_{22}\otimes e_1+e_2\otimes a_{11}+a_{11}\otimes e_2+e_3\otimes a_{11}+a_{11}\otimes e_3+e_{4}\otimes a_{22}+a_{22}\otimes e_4}$

The counit is given by (looking at this we can see the relationship between the counit and the comultiplication with respect to the unit and multiplication in a commutative, group algebra, case. To encode $ ge=g=eg$ any time there is a term of the form $ x\otimes e_1$, there must be a term of the form $ e_1\otimes x$ --- to capture the left and right symmetry $ R_\varepsilon=(I_A\otimes\varepsilon)\circ\Delta=(\varepsilon\otimes I_A)\circ \Delta=L_\varepsilon$. This also shows that, in this case, $\Delta(x)$ must contain $ x\otimes e_1$ and $ e_1\otimes x$ to encode $L_\varepsilon=I_A=R\varepsilon$):

$$ \varepsilon\left(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+\left(\begin{array}{cc}c_{11} &c_{12}\\ c_{21}&c_{22}\end{array}\right)\right)=x_1.$$

The antipode is the transpose map, i.e.

$$ S(e_i)=e_i\text{, and }S(a_{jk})=a_{ji}.$$

**Background**

A *corepresentation* $\chi$ of a finite quantum group $(A,\Delta)$ on a complex vector space $V$ is a linear map $\chi:V\rightarrow V\otimes A$ that satisfies

$$(\chi\otimes I_A)\circ \chi=(I_V\otimes \Delta)\circ\chi\text{ and }$$
$$(I_V\otimes \varepsilon)\circ \chi=I_V$$

where $\varepsilon$ is the *counit* of $(A,\Delta)$.

The dimension of the vector space is called the *dimension* of $\chi$ and is denoted by $d_\chi$.

If $W$ is a vector space which has the property that $\chi(W)\subset W\otimes A$ then $W$ is said to be *invariant* and $\chi_{|W}$ is called a *subrepresentation*.

It can be shown that $\chi$ is equivalent to a direct sum of irreducible unitary corepresentations.

Two corepresentations $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are *equivalent* as corepresentations if they admit and invertible *intertwiner*: an invertible linear map $T:V_1\rightarrow V_2$ such that

$$\chi_2\circ T=(T\otimes I_A)\circ\chi_1.$$

The space of intertwiners from $\chi_1$ to $\chi_2$ is denoted by $\text{Hom}(\chi_1,\chi_2)$.

**Further Background**

I had been under the impression that the comultiplication plays the role of the regular representation in the representation theory of finite groups so that all of the irreducible corepresentations could be found by finding subspaces $W$ of $A$ invariant under the comultiplication in the sense that $\Delta(W)\subset W\otimes A$... however I am either having a stupid misunderstanding or else this isn't as easy as I thought.

I am trying to apply the philosophy of a use of the representation theory of finite groups to the corepresentation theory of finite quantum groups and perhaps I have confused myself a little in the process!

Comment: Hang on, if all your coreps are one dimensional, wouldn't this make your example cocommutative?

Comment: (The point being that the KP example is neither commutative nor cocommutative)

Comment: @YemonChoi This is an issue that my supervisor has raised. As quantum groups, the algebra of functions on an (finite) abelian group is commutative and all of the irreps are one dimensional. However the algebra of functions on a non-abelian group is also commutative! My supervisor asks, what is an appropriate definition of an _abelian_ quantum group? Are you suggesting that cocummutative is the right answer? And does cocummutative indeed imply that all of the coreps are one dimensional?

Comment: If you want abelian quantum groups to generalize the notion of abelian group I suspect cocommutative is the right thing. But I am not an expert! (This is related to one of my pet peeves, namely that what people call quantum groups are really the co-ordinate rings of quantum groups, just as Cstar algebras are not really NC topological spaces, but the algebras of functions on NC top spaces.)

Comment: @YemonChoi I must do the sum later on... if the algebra of functions on an abelian group is cocommutative and on a non-abelian group non-cocommutative, then it sounds like a good candidate. Interestingly I was thinking about one dimensional coreps as another candidate but I understand that there are infinite dimensional non-abelian groups with one dimensional representations only.

Comment: I have since found an explicit answer to this question. The matrix elements of these five corepresentations are on p.147 of https://books.google.ie/books?id=18_UCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=kac-paljutkin+corepresentation+theory&source=bl&ots=D4uNf7kS4Z&sig=5ZUWaPpdEG2wLEwgrPnyNhT-mY0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YPeLVZkn6qzsBuqgsAg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=kac-paljutkin%20corepresentation%20theory&f=false.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy Is this a quantum group in the sense of Woronowicz? Thus a compact C*-algebraic one? If so, how can one see this?

Comment: @user839372 Yes. T. Banica and J. Bichon, Quantum groups acting on 4 points, J. Reine Angew. Math. 626 (2009), 74-114 shows that it is a quantum subgroup of the compact matrix quantum group $S_4^+$ and thus Woronowicz. If you promise to see this https://jpmccarthymaths.com/2021/03/19/intuition-for-quantum-permutations/ is a very rough draft with issues, an explicit fundamental representation is on p. 21

Comment: My understanding is that all algebras of functions on finite quantum groups are Woronowicz. 1. It should be possible, perhaps using matrix coefficients of irreducible corepresentations, to mirror the proof that compact matrix quantum groups are Woronowicz to prove directly that they satisfy Woronowicz cancellation. 2. They are Hopf*algebras with an integral so algebras of regular functions on a compact quantum group. Trivial closure is Woronowicz.

Comment: 3. I wonder can a full set of unitary irreducible corepresentation matrices form a block diagonal that is a fundamental representation for the finite quantum group so that it would be compact matrix and thus Woronowicz. I think that should work too

Comment: @JP McCarthy I like the algebraic compact quantum group approach. Any idea how you would show that these Hopf*-algebras have integrals?

Comment: They all have Haar states: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241778483_The_Haar_measure_on_finite_quantum_groups

Comment: @user839372 forgot to tag you.

Comment: @JP McCarthy Thanks! This completely solves my problem.

Comment: @user839372 you possibly need some kind of degeneracy assumption like $a^*a=0$ exactly when $a=0$. The assumption of it being C* does this. Example 3 from above shows the necessity of this I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Kac-Paljutkin Quantum Group $A$ is self-dual, i.e. the dual space $A^*$ (which is of course again finite quantum group = finite-dimesional $C^*$-Hopf algebra, with the multiplication being the dual of the coproduct of $A$ and the coproduct the dual of the multiplication of $A$) is isomorphic to $A$.

This must have been known already to Kac and Paljutkin. You can find the isomorphism, e.g., in Franz and Gohm, Random Walks on Finite Quantum Groups, in 
"Quantum Independent Increment Processes II", Lecture Notes in Mathematics Volume 1866, 2006, pp 1-32 .